# Saving Reclassed Intervals

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, reclassify

Is there a way to save reclassed intervals done on-the-fly as a layer without use of the reclass tool? I lost the reclass intervals I've created on-the-fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. What you've done is use symbology to classify the data, and symbology isn't stored in the data itself. It's either stored in the mxd, or it can be exported to a layer (.lyr) file by right-clicking the layer and choosing "Save As Layer File". Then you add the .lyr file to your map instead of the data/raster, and the symbology you set up will be applied to that data. Note if the data moves the .lyr file may load blank, but you can also add the data to a map and then apply the symbology from the layer file to it using the Import button on the symbology tab of the layer properties.

Comment: thank you Chris!It worked. I am new to ArcGIS..sometimes I panic and forget that some things can be so easy!